# Latency on a Raspberry Pi camera

Tags: python, camera, sensor, opencv

I'm making a flight controller and want to stabilize the x-y plane using optical flow, which requires almost instantaneous processing thus requires almost no latency.

How much latency does the Pi cam give? Is it acceptable for optical flow stabilization of a quadcopter? Or should I just buy an optical flow camera specifically designed for this task?

Comment: Can you quantify what an acceptable latency would be?

Comment: Approximately 5ms

Comment: Pi camera can operate to a maximum speed of 90 fps (11 ms) if you reduce the resolution to 320 x 240. So the picamera can't help your out in your project if you require a 5 ms response which is equivalent to 200 fps camera. I dont think a 200 fps camera will be cheap and light enough for your quadcopter.